# Rank of a Complex matrix in terms of its real and imaginary parts

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, reference-request, matrix-rank

Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be a complex matrix (i.e., with complex entries). We separate the real and imaginary parts of $A$ as follows: $A=A_1+iA_2$ where $A_1,A_2\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Is there any relation between the rank or determinant of $A$, $A_1$, and $A_2$? What should be the condition on $A_1,A_2$ such that $A$ will be non-singular?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think much can be said, for example we don't even have $\mathrm{rank}(A) \ge\max(\mathrm{rank}(A_1),\,\mathrm{rank}(A_2))$: let $A_1:=I$ and $A_2:=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$..

Comment: I think we can use the Sylvester’s rank inequality for the sum of two matrices: $| \textrm{rank}(A) - \textrm{rank}(B)   |   \le \textrm{rank}(A+B) \le  \textrm{rank}(A) + \textrm{rank}(B)$. I was wondering if we can say more?